# how to select specific words and put them into tuple - list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I got a result of a long string through using BeautifulSoup.
It is shaped something like this:

```
<a href="link1"><span>title1</span></a>
<a href="link2"><span>title2</span></a>
<a href="link3"><span>title3</span></a>
<a href="link4"><span>title4</span></a>
```

I want to specifically select "link#" and "title" and put them in a list - tuple like the one below:

```
[(link1,title1),(link2,title2),(link3,title3),(link4,title4)]
```

Due to my lack of understandings in python,
I don't even know what to search for.
I've been trying to do this for like 6 hours and still couldn't find the way.

the bs code i used

```
def extract(self):

    self.url ="http://aetoys.tumblr.com"
    self.source = requests.get(self.url)
    self.text = self.source.text
    self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.text)

    for self.div in self.soup.findAll('li',{'class':'has-sub'}):
        for self.li in self.div.find_all('a'):
            print(self.li)
```

Comment: *I've been trying to do this for like 6 hours and still couldnt find the way*. We can help you much better if you showed us how far you got.

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Comment: uhm thats what i am looking for too, what do i need to study?

Comment: Post the BS code you used to extract the links.

Comment: i edited the post and put the bs code i used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to extract the href:

```
out = [] # store lists of lists
for self.div in self.soup.findAll('li',{'class':'has-sub'}):
     out.append([x["href"] for x in self.div.find_all('a',href=True)])
     print([x["href"] for x in self.div.find_all('a',href=True)])



['#', '#', '/onepiece_book', '/onepiece', '#', '/naruto_book', '/naruto', '#', '/bleach_book', '/bleach', '/kingdom', '/tera', '/torico', '/titan', '/seven', '/fairytail', '/soma', '/amsal', '/berserk', '/ghoul', '/kaizi', '/piando']
['#', '/onepiece_book', '/onepiece']
['#', '/naruto_book', '/naruto']
['#', '/bleach_book', '/bleach']
['#', '/conan', '/silver', '/hai', '/nise', '/hunterbyhunter', '/baku', '/unhon', '/souleater', '/liargame', '/kenichi', '/dglayman', '/magi', '/suicide', '/pedal']
['#', '/dobaku', '/gisei', '/dragonball', '/hagaren', '/gantz', '/doctor', '/dunk', '/susi', '/reborn', '/airgear', '/island', '/crows', '/beelzebub', '/zzang', '/akira', '/tennis', '/kuroco', '/claymore', '/deathnote']
```

To get a single list:

```
url ="http://aetoys.tumblr.com"
source = requests.get(url)
text = source.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

print [ x["href"]  for div in soup.findAll('li',{'class':'has-sub'}) for x in div.find_all('a',href=True)]


['#', '#', '/onepiece_book', '/onepiece', '#', '/naruto_book', '/naruto', '#', '/bleach_book', '/bleach', '/kingdom', '/tera', '/torico', '/titan', '/seven', '/fairytail', '/soma', '/amsal', '/berserk', '/ghoul', '/kaizi', '/piando', '#', '/onepiece_book', '/onepiece', '#', '/naruto_book', '/naruto', '#', '/bleach_book', '/bleach', '#', '/conan', '/silver', '/hai', '/nise', '/hunterbyhunter', '/baku', '/unhon', '/souleater', '/liargame', '/kenichi', '/dglayman', '/magi', '/suicide', '/pedal', '#', '/dobaku', '/gisei', '/dragonball', '/hagaren', '/gantz', '/doctor', '/dunk', '/susi', '/reborn', '/airgear', '/island', '/crows', '/beelzebub', '/zzang', '/akira', '/tennis', '/kuroco', '/claymore', '/deathnote']
```

If you really want tuples:

```
out = []
for div in soup.findAll('li',{'class':'has-sub'}):
        out.append(tuple(x["href"] for x in div.find_all('a',href=True)))
```